# How to give different styling to multiple popovers in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I already have the code below in my theme/variables.scss file but it's affecting all my popovers.

```
$popover-md-width: 90%;
$popover-ios-width: 90%;
$popover-wp-width: 90%;
$popover-md-border-radius:2px;
```

Comment: those are global variables.. you will have to send cssClass to the popver you create https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution to it.

```
$popover-md-width: 90%;
$popover-ios-width: 90%;
$popover-wp-width: 90%;
$popover-md-border-radius:2px;
```

will affect the code globally, below is the fix.

In the ts file where you wrote the popover code, set a cssClass eg.

`photo1() {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create( ImageModalPage, {} , { cssClass: ' custom-popover ' });
    popover.present();
}`

Then go to your app.scss and style the popover eg.

`.custom-popover .popover-content{
    width: 90% !important;
    color: red;
    };`

Enjoy!!!

Comment: welll this only took me 4 hours to finally find this; Ionic is grand, thank you

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone who lands here for Ionic 4**

In ionic 4 the documentation states css properties of a popover are:

```
--width:    Width of the popover
```

You can set this by going to `variables.scss` and changing

```
ion-popover {
  --width: 50%
}
```

or to change a specific popover passing a css class to the popover such as:

```
const popover = await this.popoverCtrl.create({
      component: FilterComponent,
      event: event,
      translucent: true,
      cssClass: 'filterPopover'
    });
```

and then putting this in your variables.scss

```
  .filterPopover {
    --width: 70%;
  }
```

Similar to the other answer (which helped me out a lot), but not using classes ionic creates behind the scenes.